# Get string value from one column of MySQL Table and update its other column value of same row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Data Base Table whee i want to retrieve API-KEY column value and update the USED-VALUE column by 1 of the same row. I want to fetch the API-KEY value  until the USED-VALUE reach to 20, if it reach to 20 then i will retrieve API-KEY value from next row and update the USED-VALUE column by one. I want this to be repeat for all the rows. 
i am attaching my table here

[image]

Comment: Maybe you forgot to paste your php code and the full details regarding the table structure?

Comment: All columns are VARCHAR, i dont know how to start to accomplish this task

Comment: Why varchar? Use proper data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get first row where used_val is < 20 ordered by date

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE used_val < 20 ORDER BY today_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then get the ID and update used_val

```
UPDATE <table> SET used_val = CAST(used_val as INTEGER) + 1 WHERE id = <id_retrieved>;
```

Note: you should use proper data types for each column.

- today_date should be datetime or timestamp
- used_val should be integer

Comment: the today_date will be same for all rows, I am thank ful to your help please can you give me more code, how i can get the ID etc, please

Comment: U know i will have 5 record in this table forever, and i will get api_key from frist row untill its used value reach to 20 and then i will get api-key from next row,and so on.

Comment: It depends on how do you want to order your "get api". Order by id or by api_key, ASC or DESC. Look at this page to learn how to do query and get results from php: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp get the ID from the first query then update with the second one